# Pear downloading packages instead of installing after php downgrading to 5.2 on ubuntu 10.04

Tags: linux, soap, ubuntu, pear

I've downgraded php to 5.2 in ubuntu 10.04 and it seems i can't install new pear packages.
the existing packages i had by typing `pear list` are :

> Package          Version State
>   Archive_Tar      1.3.3   stable
>   Console_Getopt   1.2.3   stable
>   PEAR             1.9.0   stable
>   Structures_Graph 1.0.2   stable
>   XML_Util         1.2.1   stable

In `/usr/share/php/PEAR` there are few packages which seems not to be appearing on the list.
I wanted to install `SOAP` but the command `pear install pear.php.net/SOAP-0.12.0` is not downloading the dependent packages and instead of installing it downloads the package itself.
After a while i figured out that it was downloading in `/build/buildd/php5-5.2.10.dfsg.1/pear-build-download` but then after i changed to that path even the `pear install Mail_Mime-1.8.0.tgz` gives no output, it does not hang or anything it just gives back the prompt.the `pear list` gives the exact same output above.

How can i deal with this? thanks
P.S: i've tried on windows 7 and it downloads all the dependencies and installed everything.
thanks for reading

Comment: This may be a better thing for superuser.com

Comment: mmmh the 2 times i've tried asking question there it was ignored so i don't really know........thanks for reading anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried a using the "--force" argument?
For example:

```
 pear upgrade --force Mail_Mime-1.8.0.tgz
```