# PEAR install issue, downloads but doesn't install

Tags: php, pear

I saw [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735469/pear-downloading-packages-instead-of-installing-after-php-downgrading-to-5-2-on-u) which is exactly what I've done as well, Downgraded PHP to version 5.2 on Ubuntu 10.4

When running as root I just get the download, no install message, any thoughts?

```
pear install Mail_Mime-1.8.0.tgz
downloading Mail_Mime-1.8.0.tgz ...
Starting to download Mail_Mime-1.8.0.tgz (31,292 bytes)
.........done: 31,292 bytes
```

I've looked in the phpinfo() and see nothing except the pear path

```
include_path    .:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear    .:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear
```

running pear list I get this

```
pear list
Installed packages, channel pear.php.net:
=========================================
Package          Version State
Archive_Tar      1.3.3   stable
Console_Getopt   1.2.3   stable
PEAR             1.9.0   stable
Structures_Graph 1.0.2   stable
XML_Util         1.2.1   stable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a work around, not the best solution but it works. Using the Ubuntu Download Center, search for pear and install the needed packages. Most are listing with a prepending php-

```
php-mail
```

Answer (score 1):

please manual download Mail_Mime files and extract to /usr/share/pear/

Comment: do I have to do this because I downgraded PHP? Shouldn't PEAR install these by running the PEAR INSTALL <package> command?